# Detection of Tungsten Hexafluoride

Tags: safety

I'll be doing some work (as a software engineer) with a vacuum process chamber that consumes various nasty gases.  There are numerous safeguards in the system, but as a cautious type, I decided to read the MSDS of the chemicals involved.  The one that makes me the most nervous is tungsten hexafluoride; one mole apparently reacts with water to form 6 moles of HF, which I distantly remember from chemistry class as being bad news.  Being largely composed of water, I find this troubling.  If there were failures in the multiple safeguards and a leak did somehow occur, how could it be detected?

Comment: First off, +1 for reading the MSDS then being concerned about the potential formation of HF...really, nice going there. It looks like you've found a very serious concern, as your memories of the nastiness of HF are all too true.  Personally, I think this is such a serious issue that it is a question for a safety engineer or some such person who is thoroughly familiar with your system. You can maybe get ideas to pass on from here, but you absolutely don't want to take an answer from here as a solution to your very specific, very serious issue.  Regardless, good luck!

Comment: @airhuff, I'm sure the engineers in charge of safety are taking the proper safeguards, but I was posing this more as a question of how I could notice if something was wrong.  I.e. what would be the warning signs of a leak?  You're right that I should probably just ask the engineers, though, as they likely have plans in place for detecting and responding to serious accidents.

Comment: Yea, I didn't mean to discourage the question, it's just that chemists eyes pop out when they see "leak" and "HF" in the same paragraph ;) What is the chamber made of?

Comment: @airhuff, I don't know the precise details, but it's a heavy duty vacuum chamber and it's being built by folks who have experience working with these kinds of things.  There are several layers of safeguards (all valves are inside a  sealed box), so obviously the process guys take this stuff seriously; maybe I'm just overly paranoid.  I was thinking more: if you're working with HCN and smell almonds, you know you have a problem; not sure what you can detect if you're exposed to HF.

Comment: Your nose is very sensitive to F and Cl (and HF and HCl), at the parts per billion level. The threshold vales for harming you are higher. But, you smelling the intensely sharp acrid odor of a halogen (or halogen acid) is not, of course, calibrated. Usually continuous air monitoring is used, along with appropriate respirator protection when opening up the system.

Comment: Sorry to jump back on my safety horse one more time, but, if you can smell it, it's too late. From the Wikipedia entry for hydrofluoric acid:"Hydrogen fluoride gas is an acute poison that may immediately and permanently damage lungs and the corneas of the eyes. Aqueous hydrofluoric acid is a contact-poison with the potential for deep, initially painless burns and ensuing tissue death. By interfering with body calcium metabolism, the concentrated acid may also cause systemic toxicity and eventual cardiac arrest and fatality, after contact with as little as 160 cm2 (25 square inches) of skin.".

Answer (score 5):

$\ce{WF6}$ is not an uncommon gas used in industrial manufacturing of semi-conductors. Commercial gas detectors are readily available, and will detect $\ce{WF6}$ down to low ppm range, which is about an order of magnitude less than the $\mathrm{LC}_{50}$ for rats, apparently.

You could google tungsten hexafluoride detector, but some examples include (no affiliation or endorsement):

- http://www.newcosmos-europe.com/gas-by-name/144-tungsten-hexafluoride-detection.html
- http://www.toxicgasdetection.co.uk/gas/?gas=Tungsten%20hexafluoride&search=Tungsten%20hexafluoride&form=gas&id=416
- https://www.gas-find.com/hexafluorure-de-tungstene.html

The most common type of detector is a diffusion monitor with electrochemical sensor.
Some sensors actually use conversion of $\ce{WF6}$ to $\ce{HF}$, and then detect the $\ce{HF}$. Commercial $\ce{HF}$ detectors at low ppm range are also common.